# Не запускается DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

После установки, при запуске выдаёт ошибку `could not find main class com/intellij/idea/main`

Как это исправить?

Comment: Проверяли на последней версии?

Answer (score 1):

Уже пофикшено, ждите обновления https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240581